# TypeLoadException about Interop.Redemption.RDOSessionClass on 1 customer computer

Tags: outlook-addin, remoting, .net-remoting, outlook-redemption, outlook-2013

I have an Outlook Add-in written in .NET 4.0 which gets loaded into Outlook via [Add-In Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/), and I have another stand alone application that can invoke methods in this add-in through remoting channel using sockets. This whole thing works fine on all other computers except for 1 customer computer. The code in the add-in throws a `TypeLoadException`:

> Could not load type 'Interop.Redemption.RDOSessionClass' from assembly 'Interop.Redemption, Version=5.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fc285df3016ebc93'.

when ever the code try to create an RDOSession:

```
var session = new RDOSession();
```

The interesting thing is, that this error doesn't happen if I run the same method directly in the add-in. **It only happens when the code is invoked through the remoting channel**.

The details of the erroring computer is:

- Dell Optiplex 3010
- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
- Outlook 2013 (15.0.4701.1000) 32-bit
- The Windows user is an Administrator
- User Account Control is turned off
- I have verified that the correct Redemption DLLs are sitting in the same folder as the add-in DLL
- [**Managed Antivirus**](https://www.maxfocus.com/remote-management/managed-antivirus) is installed on this computer but disabling it doesn't seem to help
- [**Act! Pro**](http://www.act.com/) is installed which has Outlook integrations too but killing all its process doesn't seem to help

Googling this error didn't help much and I'm literally scratching my head off trying to figure it out. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to re-register Redemption with regsvr32.exe?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this using the developer version installer, and since the latest version is 5.8 so I've put assembly redirect in the config file in the add-in to redirect 5.5 to 5.8 but the problem remains. I don't think Redemption registration is the problem because I can run test code that creates new RDOSession fine directly in the add-in, but once I try invoking the same code via remoting the same error happens. Almost looks like some sort of security or permission issue that denies the remoting call to access the DLL.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "remoting"? Do you mean you create RDOSesssion in one process and marshal it to another? Why would you want to do that?